# Manage parent/child table

Tags: database-design, table

I need to realize a software to manage some projects. Every project starts after a offer approvation.
A offer could have many revision, but only the last one offer is the parent of the project.

Example:

```
price_quotation_a => project
```

OR

```
price_quotation_a
price_quotation_b
price_quotation_c => project
```

My idea is to realize only one table, with a flag (**type**) to distinguish order from project. A second column (**parent**) to specify for every order wich offer is the parent.
The problem is that offer and project have the same data.

```
+----+------+--------+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| id | type | parent | name | revision | project_name | project_desc |
+----+------+--------+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |    0 |      0 | O001 | A        | Project01    | Project_desc |
|  2 |    0 |      0 | O001 | B        | Project01    | Project_desc |
|  3 |    1 |      2 | P001 | NULL     | Project01    | Project_desc |
|  4 |    0 |      0 | O002 | A        | Project02    | Project_desc |
|  5 |    1 |      4 | P002 | NULL     | Project02    | Project_desc |
+----+------+--------+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Operatos must insert worked hours both for order or offer so i need a list with both entity. Something like:

```
+----+-------------+----------+----------------+-------+
| id |    date     | operator | order/offer ID | hours |
+----+-------------+----------+----------------+-------+
|  1 | 01-010-2002 |       12 |              1 |     5 |
|  2 | 01-010-2002 |       12 |              2 |     6 |
|  3 | 01-010-2002 |        5 |              1 |     4 |
+----+-------------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

Shout if I haven't bee clear. It's the right way?

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Employee (aka operator) EMP exists.
--
employee {EMP}
      PK {EMP}
```

```
-- Customer CST exists.
--
customer {CST}
      PK {CST}
```

```
-- On date RFQ_DTE, request for quotation
-- number RFQ_NO was received from customer CST.
--
rfq_in {CST, RFQ_NO, RFQ_DTE}
    PK {CST, RFQ_NO}

FK {CST} REFERENCES customer {CST}
```

```
-- Project PRO was started on date PRO_DTE
-- in response to request for quotation
-- number RFQ_NO from customer CST.
--
project {PRO, CST, RFQ_NO, PRO_DTE}
     PK {PRO}
     AK {CST, RFQ_NO}

FK {CST, RFQ_NO} REFERENCES rfq_in {CST, RFQ_NO}
```

```
-- Offer revision REV for project PRO
-- was created on date OFR_DTE.
--
offer {PRO, REV, OFR_DTE}
   PK {PRO, REV}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES project {PRO}
```

```
-- On date OW_DTE employee EMP spent OW_HRS hours
-- working on offer revision REV for project PRO.
--
offer_work {PRO, REV, EMP, OW_DTE, OW_HRS}
        PK {PRO, REV, EMP, OW_DTE}

FK1 {PRO, REV} REFERENCES offer {PRO, REV}

FK2 {EMP} REFERENCES employee {EMP}
```

```
-- Offer revision REV for project PRO
-- was accepted and approved on date APR_DTE.
--
accepted {PRO, REV, APR_DTE}
      PK {PRO}

FK {PRO, REV} REFERENCES offer {PRO, REV}
```

```
-- On date PW_DTE employee EMP spent PW_HRS hours
-- working on project PRO.
--
project_work {PRO, EMP, PW_DTE, PW_HRS}
          PK {PRO, EMP, PW_DTE}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES accepted {PRO}
FK2 {EMP} REFERENCES employee {EMP}
```

Create a view to report work hours.

```sql
CREATE VIEW work_hours
AS
SELECT OW_DTE AS DTE
     , EMP
     , OW_HRS AS HRS
     , PRO
     , 'O'    AS WRK_TYPE
     , ('offer revision ' || REV) AS DETAIL
FROM offer_work
UNION
SELECT PW_DTE AS DTE
     , EMP
     , PW_HRS AS HRS
     , PRO
     , 'P'    AS WRK_TYPE
     , 'some project work' AS DETAIL
FROM project_work
;
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```